# Display string as link in React's forEach

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an array of links as shown below:

[image]

I need to render it as a links, I am trying to do it like:

```
export const LinksPure = (props: AllProps) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const { component } = props;

  return (
    <DetailsBox title={t('catalogPage.componentDetails.specs.links')}>
      <Typography variant="body1" component="p" gutterBottom>
        {component?.external_links.forEach(link => {
          // link
        })}
      </Typography>
    </DetailsBox>
  );
};
```

Below a mock of effect which I want to have:

[image]

How to format those strings in `forEach` to transform it into links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` always returns `undefined`, which won't render anything. Use `map`.

```
{component?.external_links.map(link => <a>...</a>)}
```